# What's the difference with trash_comment and wp_trash_comment?

Tags: comments, trash

I don't understand when I'm suppose to use trash_comment over wp_trash_comment.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you see `trash_comment`? It is no original WordPress core **function**, though. Maybe some part of a plugin/theme?

So in short: use [`wp_trash_comment`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1213) - if you must.

There is, however, an **action** called [`trash_comment`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1233). Maybe this is what got you confused...?

Comment: Oh my... so wp_trash_comment isnt even an action? Bah!!

Comment: I'm a little confused since wp_trash_post seems to be an action that works in my script, but wp_trash_comment doesnt.

Comment: No, `wp_trash_comment` is a function that you call (with a comment ID) to trash the comment. And `trash_comment` is an action (in this very function) that you can use for custom functions to _hook in_.